# How do I get a shared value in Fastlane?

Tags: fastlane

I use the `changelog_from_git_commits` Fastlane action to gather a changelog from the commit logs. The output ends up in a `FL_CHANGELOG` variable:

```
Actions.lane_context[SharedValues::FL_CHANGELOG] = changelog
```

Now I would like to post the changelog along with my Slack notification:

```
slack(payload: { 'Changelog' => WHAT_DO_I_WRITE_HERE? })
```

What do I write there? `ENV["FL_CHANGELOG"]` didn’t work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked:

```
payload: { 'Changelog' => Actions.lane_context[SharedValues::FL_CHANGELOG] })
```